# SQL: select unique substrings from the table by mask

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

There is a SQL table `mytable` that has a column `mycolumn`.
That column has text inside each cell. Each cell may contain "this.text/31/" or "this.text/72/" **substrings** (numbers in that substrings can be any) as a part of string.

What SQL query should be executed to display a list of unique such substrings?

P.S. Of course, some cells may contain several such substrings.

And here are the answers for questions from the comments:
The query supposed to work on SQL Server.
The prefered output should contain the whole substring, not the numeric part only. It actually could be not just the number between first "/" and the second "/".

And it is varchar type (probably)

Example:
`mycolumn` contains such values:

```
abcd/eftthis.text/31/sadflh adslkjh
abcd/eftthis.text/44/khjgb ljgnkhj this.text/447/lhkjgnkjh
ljgkhjgadsvlkgnl
uygouyg/this.text/31/luinluinlugnthis.text/31/ouygnouyg
khjgbkjyghbk
```

The query should display:

```
this.text/31/
this.text/44/
this.text/447/
```

Comment: so you want the numeric part only? can you clarify desired output based on a sample dataset?

Comment: So this cell is a `varchar` type?

Comment: Are your query supposed to work on both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: Why doesn't `SELECT DISTINCT mycolumn FROM mytable` work?

Comment: I put answers on your questions to the description above. Thank you.

Comment: @Salman A:  "this.text/72/" is a substring of the cell, not the cell value. It is a part of the cell value.

Comment: If `this.text/72/` is a substring, what other strings are present inside the cell? Post some sample data, it will help.

Comment: Use POSITION to find "this.text/", then use to POSITION to find the next "/". Use SUBSTRING to pick out that part of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a recursive CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable
(
myColumn VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #myTable
VALUES
    ('abcd/eftthis.text/31/sadflh adslkjh'),
    ('abcd/eftthis.text/44/khjgb ljgnkhj this.text/447/lhkjgnkjh'),
    ('ljgkhjgadsvlkgnl'),
    ('uygouyg/this.text/31/luinluinlugnthis.text/31/ouygnouyg'),
    ('khjgbkjyghbk')


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT MyColumn, 
    CHARINDEX('this.text/', myColumn, 0)  AS startPos,
    CHARINDEX('/', myColumn, CHARINDEX('this.text/', myColumn, 1) + 10) AS endPos
    FROM #myTable
    WHERE myColumn LIKE '%this.text/%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.MyColumn, 
    CHARINDEX('this.text/', T1.myColumn, C.endPos) AS startPos,
    CHARINDEX('/', T1.myColumn, CHARINDEX('this.text/', T1.myColumn, c.endPos) + 10) AS endPos
    FROM #myTable T1
    INNER JOIN CTE C
        ON C.myColumn = T1.myColumn
    WHERE SUBSTRING(T1.MyColumn, C.EndPos, 100) LIKE '%this.text/%'

)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(myColumn, startPos, EndPos - startPos)
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a table named test with the following data:

```
COLUMN1
aathis.text/31/
this.text/1/
bbbthis.text/72/sksk
```

could this be what you are looking for?

```
select SUBSTR(COLUMN1,INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 ),INSTR(COLUMN1,'/',INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 )+10) - INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 )+1) from test;
```

result:

```
this.text/31/
this.text/1/
this.text/72/
```

---

i see your problem:

Assume the same table as above but now with the following data:

```
this.text/77/
xxthis.text/33/xx
xthis.text/11/xxthis.text/22/x
xthis.text/1/x
```

The following might help you:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1, INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 ,1), INSTR(COLUMN1,'/',INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 ,1)+10) - INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 ,1)+1) FROM TEST
UNION
SELECT CASE WHEN (INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1,2 ) >0) THEN 
       SUBSTR(COLUMN1, INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1,2 ), INSTR(COLUMN1,'/',INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1 ,2),2) - INSTR(COLUMN1,'this.text', 1,2 )+1) end FROM TEST;
```

it will generate the following result:

```
this.text/1/
this.text/11/
this.text/22/
this.text/33/
this.text/77/
```

The downside is that you need to add a select statement for every occurance you might have of "this.text". If you might have 100 "this.text" in the same cell it might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQL> select SUBSTR(column_name,1,9) from tablename;

column_name

---

this.text

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name,'this.text/[[:digit:]]+/') 
FROM table_name
```